# Add items to comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

So I am trying to add items to a comboBox like this (the comboBox itself looks fine; it appears on screen and everything):

```
people_comboBox.Items.Add("Present");
people_comboBox.Items.Add("Late");
people_comboBox.Items.Add("Absent");
```

It only comes up with one item, which is "System.String[]".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: WinForms, WPF? A little more information and if WPF, some XAML would really help.

Comment: your code is fine to me.. bt share other information like is it win form or something else.. like @lordtakkera asked

Comment: It is simple C# winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating List or Array of strings with those values and then set `.DataSource` property of ComboBox to this collection.